# How to use category in Swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking in my project, I want to create refreshcontroller in #import "UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.h" 
but in swift I can only `let refreshControl: UIRefreshControl` any way I can import like objc

```
#import "UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.h"
```

that I can use the refreshcontroller in UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.h

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the import in your bridging header file, check out [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_79)

Then it is the same way you interoperate normally with Objective-C.

`refreshControler.setRefreshingWithStateOfTask(task)`